# SQL-запрос на противоположные данные

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

---

номер поставщик|номер детали

```
|1|1|
|1|1|
|2|3|
|2|2|
|2|3|
|2|5|
|3|3|
|3|4|
|4|6|
```

Как сделать запрос, который покажет пары  "номер поставщика-номер детали", такие что данный поставщик не поставляет данную деталь. То есть должно получится

```
|1|3|
|1|5|
|1|4|
|1|6|
|2|1|
|2|4|
|2|6|
```

ну и тд

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
SELECT t1.id1, t2.id2
FROM test AS t1, test AS t2
WHERE (t1.id1, t2.id2) NOT IN (SELECT t3.* FROM test AS t3)
GROUP BY t1.id1, t2.id2
```

где id1 - ID поставщика, id2 - ID товара. Это если одним запросом делать, но при большом количестве данных будет сильно тормозить, т.к. внутренний запрос будет вызываться каждый раз, т.е. его лучше заранее сделать как представление. К тому же таблица t1 нужна, чтобы ID поставщика получить, т.е. лучше заменить на таблицу поставщиков - увеличится скорость (таким способом я для каждой записи получаю ID, а затем для этого ID повторяю всю операцию, а ведь в этой таблице id1 может встречаться гораздо больше 100 раз, т.е. для одного и того же ID будет повторяться все снова и снова). То же самое и для t2 - используется для товара
Т.е., как вариант:

```
SELECT id1, id2
FROM test AS t1, test AS t2
WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM test)
GROUP BY id1, id2
```

где t1 - таблица поставщиков id1 - ID поставщика, t2 - таблица продуктов ID2 - ID продукта, test - поставки - тогда для каждого поставщика и каждого продукта проверяем - была поставка или нет. И опять же - внутренний SELECT лучше сделать заранее

Comment: >`#1241 - Operand should contain 2 column(s)`

вот такую ошибку он выдает

Comment: Что именно слабо понимаешь? И что значит: "на релецеонном запросе показать"?
Последний код простой: создаем пары (поставщик, продукт) (SELECT id1, id2 FROM id1, id2) - т.е. (1,1), (1,2), ... (2,1), (2,2)...(4,6) - далее среди этого набора ищем те, которые отсутствуют в исходной таблице (WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN (SELECT * FROM test)) - работа сделана, а (GROUP BY id1, id2) используется только для того, чтобы показывало какие продукты поставщик не заказал ((1,2), (1,3)...), у меня отображалось - какие поставщики не заказали продукт ((2,1), (3,1)...) - результат тот же, способ отображения другой

Comment: спс за комент все понял

Comment: Возможно в табличке выводится не 2, а более столбцов. test - твоя таблица, id1 - поставщик, id2 - товар. Вместо "SELECT * FROM test" попробуй "SELECT test.id1, test.id2 FROM test"

Comment: слушай а как этот запрос сделать в реляционной алгебре а то у меня требование sql и реляционная алгебра

Comment: Про реляционную алгебру ничего уже не помню, так что могу только предположить: (id1 UNION id2) WHERE (id1, id2) NOT IN test. Только, чтобы читалось нормально будет лучше заменить название таблиц или столбцов.

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать так:

```
select
  t1.maker,
  t2.product
from
  (
    select distinct
      maker
    from
      table
  ) t1,
  (
    select distinct
      product
    from
      table
  ) t2
where
  not exists (
    select 1
    from
      table t3
    where
      t3.maker = t1.maker and
      t3.product = t2.product
  )
```